# Why does the Maybe return type make this crash?

Tags: haskell

I'm restricting myself the use of prebuilt-in functions for training purposes. I have recoded length as count and it works.

I have a search funtion that simply returns a value at index in a list when given an index and a list. It works completly fine. It throws an error when the index is too large.

```hs
search [] _ = error "index too large"
search (a:_) 0 = a
search (_:a) b = search a (b - 1)
```

Now, I want a `safeSearch` function that return `Nothing` if the index is too large of if the list is empty. So I've simply done this.

```hs
safeSearch :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
safeSearch a b
  | b < 0 || b >= count a = Nothing
  | otherwise = Just (search a b)
```

And it works! ... as long as you don't try it on an empty list. Even with an index too large for the list length.

```hs
main = print(safeSearch [] 5)
```

This crashes and I really can't find any way around it.

Even though I don't think my second line is usefull (because if the list is empty, its count is 0 so we drop in the first guard and it should return Nothing?) its not working. Removing it does not solve the problem.

Here's the compile-time error.

```
main.hs:91:8: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `print'
      prevents the constraint `(Show a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
        ...plus 22 others
        ...plus 13 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In the expression: print (safeSearch [] 5)
      In an equation for `main': main = print (safeSearch [] 5)
   |
91 | main = print(safeSearch [] 5)
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
exit status 1
```

Any idea? Something I'm missing or even completly going wrong? A concept I need to understand deeper?

Comment: You should give a hint what type of list it is `main = print(safeSearch ([] :: [Int]) 5)`

Comment: What if I want it to work without? Am I way off or is it simply a tiny thing? I would like it to work simply by giving the values... @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: You can use the `ExtendedDefaultRules` extension to have it defaulted as `[] :: [()]`.

Comment: Note that `print []` will already cause the ambiguity error. Haskell must know the type for that empty list, also because `[] :: [Int]` and `[] :: [Char]` are printed differently, so the type does matter and the ambiguity must be resolved.

Comment: Why define `safeSearch` in terms of `search`? All you need to do is replace `error` with `None` and `a` with `Just a`.

Comment: If by None you meant Nothing, it does not work. Exactly the same problem. Else, I do not know None and wan't find anything about it. Would you like to explain so I understand? Thanks @chepner!

Comment: It's not a solution to your immediate typechecking problem, but it's a simpler design. You are essentially trying to wrap an unsafe function by anticipating the inputs that make it unsafe, instead of making it safe from the start. `safeSearch [] _ = Nothing; safeSearch (a:_) 0 = Just a; safeSearch (_:a) b = safeSearch a (b-1)`. (And yes, I meant `Nothing`: I blame too much switching back and forth between Python and Haskell.)

Comment: You blame this on switching to `Maybe`. But `main = print (search [] 5)` has the same problem, so it isn't `Maybe`'s fault!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a **compile** error. That means it isn't actually running your code and hitting your `error "index too large"` call; the compiler is rejecting your code before it can even try to run it. So you're looking in the wrong place if you're trying to change the code to avoid that.

What's actually happening is that `safeSearch [] 5` is returning a value of type `Maybe a`, where `a` is the type of the elements in the list. But you didn't include any elements in the list, so there is nothing at all to decide what that type `a` is.

Your function `safeSearch` can work for any type, so that's actually fine. But you also try to `print` the `Maybe a` value. Using `print` requires a `Show` instance, and the instance for `Maybe a` requires there to also be a `Show` instance for `a`. Because there is nothing saying what type `a` is, the compiler has no way of finding the appropriate `Show` instance for it, so it has to abort compilation with an error.

The most straightforward way to solve it is to add a type annotation (either of the list, or the `Maybe a` value resulting from `safeSearch`). Something like this:

```
main = print (safeSearch ([] :: [Int]) 5)
```

(This is what the error message is talking about when it says an ambiguous type variable is preventing a `Show` constraint from being solved, and that the probable fix is to add a type annotation)

Note that this sort of issue is rarely a problem in "real" code. Normally if you have a list processed into another structure with a related type, you will have other code that does something with the elements or the result, or that produced the list (which isn't always empty). You wouldn't normally write a program that does nothing but process an always-empty list and print the result, *except* for these kinds of quick tests. So normally, when there is that other code as well, there will be enough context for the compiler to deduce the type of your empty list, and the extra type annotations will not be needed. So this kind of extra type annotation is not usually considered a serious burden that needs to be avoided, because they are hardly ever needed in "real" code. You just code as you want, and  on the occassion that a compile error makes your realise you need an annotation you simply add it and move on.

If you do this kind of quick check in GHCi rather than writing a full program with a `main` function, then you also would not have needed the extra type annotation. This is because GHCi has the `ExtendedDefaultRules` language extension turned on by default. The "default rules" are conditions when GHC will choose a type for you instead of throwing an "ambiguous type" error. The normal default rules are pretty strict, and really only designed for defaulting numeric constraints (like `Num a` or `Real a`, etc). They do not apply to your original example. The "extended default rules" apply more often to avoid needing lots of type signatures in the interactive interpreter (since there you enter one line at a time, instead of the compiler being able to see the full module to infer types from usage). In this case entering `print (safeSearch [] 5)` at the interpreter prompt will work because it defaults the returned type to `Maybe ()`, and it just so happens that printing `Nothing :: Maybe ()` produces the same output as it would if it had correctly guessed the type you actually meant.

But in almost any real program, defaulting a type variable to `()` will be a stupid thing to do that makes things work *less*, so I do not recommend getting into the habit of enabling `ExtendedDefaultRules` in an actual module. Just add the type annotation, or do quick checks in the interpreter instead of in a module.

Comment: This is what I needed to understand! Loads of clear informations, thanks! I still want it to work without having to give context to trully understand but now I know where to search for.

Answer (score 0):

What you've written works great for any real-world use case. It only fails when someone writes `print (safeSearch [] x)` - a literal empty list, with no context to tell what result type is expected. It works fine if they pass in a nonempty list, or a list expression that happens to evaluate to an empty list, or if they use the result in a way that lets type inference figure out what was intended.

Further, there is really no way to write the function so that it works when passed a contextless empty list. The burden to make the types clear is necessarily placed on call sites, not the definition. The comments on your question have already shown how to do this; you only have to be that explicit when you're calling your function in a way that's obviously useless.